# Requesting oidc access token from spa

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement an oidc client with keycloak for a react single-page application.

The react frontend needs to access a Java-API, which requires a signed JWT from a configured oidc server (in my case keycloak).

We want to avoid storing the client-secret within the react-application, as it seems to be a rather bad practice (as the name already implies).

I did manage to get it running when using "Implicit flow"; however, i fail to upgrade it to something like "Authorization code flow with pkce", as described in articles like [this](https://codeburst.io/authorization-code-flow-with-pkce-oauth-in-a-react-application-dcc4e06798df).

I'm currently posting a request to the `/auth/realms/Test/protocol/openid-connect/auth`, with following query parameters:

```
client_id = "client_id";
response_type = "code";
redirect_uri = "http://localhost/login.html";
scope = "openid";
nonce = "eGT0IRjpaz-USQSg2hoipYb3TEBAaSce";
code_challenge = "ZjFmNzM1YTBlMmMzZjk5MjMwNTk5NzE2Y2Q3M2MxZTdlYzhhYjVkYzRkN2YzN2EyYTBmYWJiNDUw";
code_challenge_method = "S256";
```

This works so far, and I receive the session_state and code as a query parameter on the login.html site.

However, that's where my confusion starts:

1. Why are thous query parameters, shouldn't they be within the hash, so that the response isn't sent to the server?
2. How to continue?

As far as I know, the next step would be to exchange these values for an actual token, by calling the `/token` endpoint.

But when I do that, keycloak will at some point start complaining about a missing client_secret, which I don't want to provide.

Example params (form url encoded):

```
grant_type = authorization_code
code = <response from /auth>
redirect_uri = http://localhost/login.html
client_id = client_id
client_session = <response from /auth>
```

So my question: where did I go wrong?

It seems like I'm either using another flow and didn't realize it, misunderstand the flow entirely or I'm just not providing a specific parameter and keycloak complains about another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a `code_verifier` field to redeem the authorization code for tokens. See the messages in steps 4 and 8 of my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/).

Aim to use a library that does this for you, as in [this class of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L126) where I only need to call `signInRedirectCallback`.

It is standard to return the authorization code in the query string. It can only be used once, and if intercepted somehow an attacker cannot use it because they do not have the code verifier.

**SHORT TERM**

You will have implemented PKCE basics correctly for an SPA, which should get you up and running for a while.

**LONGER TERM**

SPA security is trickier than you may realise, and in 2021 it is no longer recommended to implement it solely in the browser. See [these Curity resources](https://curity.io/product/token-service/oauth-for-web/) if you run into problems later, in areas such as access token renewal.